# So few questions

Tags: discussion

Everyone seems to have stopped posting questions. How come?

Answer (score 11):

All Stack-like sites experience a drastic reduction of activity over the weekend.  It's rather dramatic; I remember seeing a chart of StackOverflow traffic over the days of the week that had such a dramatic drop in activity for the weekend that my entire worldview was forever altered.

Another possible factor might be in the composition of the Private Beta team.  It could be that most of the people who committed are people who are more interested in answering questions than asking them.

All this means is that we must up our seeding ante before the big day!

Comment: I strongly suspect Sunday night is just not a big time for people to be online.

Comment: Ah, right, different timezone

Comment: Oops, sorry, I suppose we're being a little ameri-centric.

I think Mad Men premiered tonight, too, and there were also new episodes of True Blood and Entourage, for what that's worth.

Comment: Yep, even big sites traffic will drop like 25%

Comment: Isaac is right, I have lots of other things to do during the weekend.